# Alpine js get "tag input" as array

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I've found a really cool tag input code with alpine js and tailwind css. It works just fine, but when I try to send it with my form, I always get the last tag only. I'd like to push them into an array and send along with the other elements in the form, but I don't know how to do that. Here's the working example of the tag input I use: https://codepen.io/atomgiant/pen/QWjWgKz

This is the html part:

```
<div data-tags='[]'
            class="mb-8">
        <div x-data="tagSelect()" x-init="init('parentEl')" @click.away="clearSearch()"
                @keydown.escape="clearSearch()">
            <div class="relative" @keydown.enter.prevent="addTag(textInput)">
                <input x-model="textInput" x-ref="textInput"
                        @input="search($event.target.value)"
                        class="block w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 rounded bg-gray-200 text-gray-600 border-gray-600 focus:border-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring"
                        placeholder="Enter some tags">
                <div :class="[open ? 'block' : 'hidden']">
                    <div class="absolute z-40 left-0 mt-2 w-full">
                        <div class="py-1 text-sm bg-white rounded shadow-lg border border-gray-300">
                            <a @click.prevent="addTag(textInput)"
                                class="block py-1 px-5 cursor-pointer hover:bg-indigo-600 hover:text-white">Add tag: "<span class="font-semibold"
                                                    x-text="textInput"></span>"</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- selections -->
                <template x-for="(tag, index) in tags">
                    <div class="bg-indigo-100 inline-flex items-center text-sm rounded mt-2 mr-1">
                        <span class="ml-2 mr-1 leading-relaxed truncate max-w-xs"
                                x-text="tag"></span>
                        <button @click.prevent="removeTag(index)"
                                class="w-6 h-8 inline-block align-middle text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-600 focus:outline-none">
                            <svg class="w-6 h-6 fill-current mx-auto"
                                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                        d="M15.78 14.36a1 1 0 0 1-1.42 1.42l-2.82-2.83-2.83 2.83a1 1 0 1 1-1.42-1.42l2.83-2.82L7.3 8.7a1 1 0 0 1 1.42-1.42l2.83 2.83 2.82-2.83a1 1 0 0 1 1.42 1.42l-2.83 2.83 2.83 2.82z"/>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the JS part for the tag input:

```
function tagSelect() {
    return {
        open: false,
        textInput: '',
        tags: [],
        init() {
            this.tags = JSON.parse(this.$el.parentNode.getAttribute('data-tags'));
        },
        addTag(tag) {
            tag = tag.trim()
            if (tag != "" && !this.hasTag(tag)) {
                this.tags.push( tag )
            }
            this.clearSearch()
            this.$refs.textInput.focus()
            this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
        },
        fireTagsUpdateEvent() {
            this.$el.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('tags-update', {
                detail: { tags: this.tags },
                bubbles: true,
            }));
        },
        hasTag(tag) {
            var tag = this.tags.find(e => {
                return e.toLowerCase() === tag.toLowerCase()
            })
            return tag != undefined
        },
        removeTag(index) {
            this.tags.splice(index, 1)
            this.fireTagsUpdateEvent()
        },
        search(q) {
            if ( q.includes(",") ) {
                q.split(",").forEach(function(val) {
                    this.addTag(val)
                }, this)
            }
            this.toggleSearch()
        },
        clearSearch() {
            this.textInput = ''
            this.toggleSearch()
        },
        toggleSearch() {
            this.open = this.textInput != ''
        }
    }
}
```

and this is where I fetch the form. I'd like to get the data in the `tags[]` array.

```
function contentUploadModal() {
    return {
        contentForm: {
            title: "",
            content: "",
            public: "",
            tags: [],
            detail: {
            }
        },
        errorMessage: "",
        createSuccess: false,
        sendContentUpload(contentForm) {
            console.log(contentForm)
            this.errorMessage = ""
            this.createSuccess = false
            fetch('/api/content', {
                method: 'POST',
                cache: "no-cache",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                redirect: "follow",
                body: JSON.stringify(contentForm)
            })
                .then(response => {
                    response.json()
                        .then(json => {
                            if (json['success'] === true) {
                                this.createSuccess = true
                                setTimeout((() => window.location.reload()), 100)
                            } else {
                                this.errorMessage = json['error']
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(() => this.errorMessage = 'Error. Check again!')
                })
                .catch(err => this.errorMessage = 'Unknown error!')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built in event listener on the container div that gets fired when you add or remove a tag. You can either put a function in there, or just have it set a variable.

In your script somewhere, instantiate the array

```
let myTags = []
```

then set it in your main container

```
<div x-data @tags-update="myTags= $event.detail.tags" data-tags='[]' class="max-w-lg m-6">
```

Then in your form submit, capture the value after the function starts

```
sendContentUpload(contentForm) {
  contentForm.tags = myTags;    
  console.log('contentForm',contentForm)
```

The only caveat is, I can't figure out how to initialize `data-tags` with `myTags`. You could leave it hard coded like you did (["aaa","bbb"]) but I removed that. Take a look at my pen.

Example: https://codepen.io/john-tyner/pen/jOBxGNo?editors=1111

Comment: I added the myTags array to the first line in my js, above the contentUploadModal function.  Changed the ```tags: []``` to ```tags: myTags``` inside the return part and copied the div you suggested, but my tags array is still empty.

Comment: Can you include in your codepen the code where you submit your form?

Comment: Can you open it if I send it like this? https://codepen.io/MowerQQ/pen/GRWdEaj

Comment: Ok, it's working here: https://codepen.io/john-tyner/pen/wvJjqKr?editors=1111  -- I removed `x-model` b/c it was overriding the array and reinserted `x-data` - I wasn't sure how your `contentUploadModal() ` function was supposed to work since the function you were actually calling was nested inside that. I removed the outer part and now you'll see in the console.log that it is getting `myData`

Comment: Sorry for being so incomprehensible but I can't remove the contentUploadModal because that opens the modal that contains the whole form. I updated my codepen with the whole modal now (sorry I didn't do it first), but as you can see, tags don't show up for me. If you could take a last look at it, I'd be really grateful. https://codepen.io/MowerQQ/pen/GRWdEaj?editors=1111